# How to center x axis values on seaborn histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I know that when `discrete = True`, x-axis values are aligned on the center. However, I don't understand why it brakes when it comes to creating histogram with certain bin number (e.g., when setting a bins value of 19):

```
sns.histplot(data=df_ckd, x="HEIGHT", hue="SEX", multiple="stack",bins=19)
plt.xticks(np.arange(32, 198, 12))
plt.show()
```

How can I put those x axis values in the center?

[image]

Comment: With `bins=19`, the range from the smallest till the largest is divided in 19 equal parts, so 20 bin edges.  The bars are put nicely onto these edges.  What exactly do you want to achieve?  Maybe you could try something like `bins=np.arange(0,201,20)`? Or `bns=np.arange(32,198,12)`?

Comment: @JohanC I would like to display x- axis value on the center of each barplot/rectangle for example like value 32 should be in the middle of first bar not aligned in the left ...

Comment: Why do you expect the specific x tick values that you passed to be located in the center of the bins?

Comment: @mwaskom to articulate the visualization and make it easy to read for the reader

Comment: What I'm asking is: you're asking for 19 bins and 14 ticks. How do you expect to be able to put 14 ticks at the center of each of 19 bins?

Comment: @mwaskom I would liek to show 14 bins and 14 ticks. 19 bins are not a must

Comment: `bins=np.arange(32,198,12)` and `plt.xticks( np.arange(38,198,12) )` would label the centers of the bars (which are the centers of the bin edges).  Or `bins=np.arange(26,198,12)` together with `plt.xtcks(np.arange(32,198,12))`.

Comment: @JohanC can you post your comment as an answer so that  I can choose it as the correct answer? Also, can you explain how did you calculate right number of bins and xticks so that x axis values are in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you have to calculate some values first.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
penguins = penguins.dropna()

max_n = penguins.flipper_length_mm.max()
min_n = penguins.flipper_length_mm.min()
bins = 15
step = (max_n - min_n) / bins
print(min_n, max_n, bins, step)
# 172.0 231.0 15 3.933333333333333

arr_div = np.arange(min_n + step / 2, max_n + step / 2, step=step)
arr_div_r = np.round(arr_div, 0).astype(int)

sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", hue="sex", bins=bins, multiple="stack")
plt.xticks(arr_div, arr_div_r)
# To see the real values without rounding
# plt.xticks(arr_div)

plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram with centered labels (x axis)]

Comment: how to show the minimum value (172) instead of the 174?

Comment: @dspractician You would have to change `arr_div_r`, the first element is 174 which is the first label you see on x axis.

Answer (score -1):

You can use xlim, example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = [5,8,12,18,19,19.9,20.1,21,24,28] 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(data, ax=ax)  # distplot is deprecate and replaced by histplot
ax.set_xlim(1,31)
ax.set_xticks(range(1,32))
plt.show()
```